# unity webgl fill browser, but preserve aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, unity-game-engine, webgl

I would like to change the size of the unity player container so that it would fill the browser window, but at the same time preserve the aspect ratio.

In the unity inspector having the 16:9 aspect ratio and dragging around the game view works fine. Once I build it and the div size is set to 1920 x 1080px everything works fine aswell. However once I change the div style in the index.html to something like:

```
<div id="unityContainer" style = "position: absolute; right:50%; top:50%; transform:translate(50%,-50%); max-height:100%;min-height:100%;;</div>
```

the ratio is definitely not preserved.(I read somewhere that if you do not specify the other dimension it should automatically preserve the ratio) Here is the webpage in question [umgebung.digital](http://umgebung.digital). (the line by the "browse" text should be touching the perpendicular line) I have found maybe possible solutions for this in javascript, however I was thinking that perhaps there is a simpler way to do this.

Thank you for any possible thoughts !

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using:

```
<div id="unityContainer" style = " ..... height:100%; aspect-ratio:16/9;"></div>
```

but supposedly this will not function in safari browser.

Answer (score 0):

With scss, example with ratio 16:9:

```
canvas {
  width: min(calc(100vh * (16/9)), 100vw);
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  display: block;
}
```